# App crashes when UIView is added to views hierarchy but only in production builds (not in debug)

Tags: ios, debugging, uiview, ios-keyboard-extension

I am having strange bug that is very hard to debug:

- I am creating complex `UIView` (specificaly `UIScrollView`) with many subvies and then I add this to views hierarchy in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`
- When I debug it all works nicely
- When compiled for running and installed via TestFlight it crashes. No crash logs are found on the device about this crashes!
- The creation of the view does not cause crash in production build (verified by trial and error), the app crashes only when it is added to superview.

The detailed situation is as follows: The app is keyboard extension written is Swift, I have portrait and landscape version of keyboard created in advance. In `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` I remove displayed keyboard version from its super view and add the other instead. This works fine in debug mode. In production builds both landscape and portrait will display nicely. Only replacing one with another during rotation causes the crash (always).

Anybody encountered similar situation? Any ideas on how to efectively debug or what can be causing it?

Comment: Try changing Swift Compiler Optimization to None in build settings of your target.

Comment: did you get the crash by customer report? have you tried to hook up lldb to see what happened? if you cannot use lldb to reproduce, use something like crashlytics to capture crash logs in the fields

Answer (score 0):

Here is what is going on in my app, maybe somebody will find it useful:

The crash is caused by adding to many views to hierarchy. Probably it does not fit into memory or something like that.

Strange things are that it does not happen in debug mode. Another strange thing is that when I 700 views does not cause crash, but removing those 700 from hierarchy and adding another 700 does cause crash...